# Extract value from JSON that matches a column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having the following issue. I have a table like the following that holds all the exchange rates per day for all currencies (as base currency is Euro):

| id | rates_values | rate_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"AED":2.835349,"AFN":67.743417,... | 1-1-2022 |
| 2 | {"AED":2.485349,"AFN":66.843814, | 2-2-2022 |

The column rates_values is in JSON. I have another table which is like the following one:

| currency | cost | date_of_sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AED | 150 | 1-1-2022 |
| AFN | 250 | 2-2-2022 |
| EUR | 56 | 2-2-2022 |

I join these 2 tables on date.
As next step, I want to extract the value that is referred on the currency column from the rates_values column but I don't know how. A desirable result would be the below:

| currency | extracted_values_for_each_sale |
| --- | --- |
| AED | 2.835349 |
| AFN | 66.843814 |
| EUR | 1 |

I can write a really long CASE...WHEN... statement and each time extract the matching value but that's not the optimal solution.

Comment: Have you tried something like this `(rates_values->currency)::float`?

Comment: I couldn't imagine that this could work! Thank you so much sir!

Comment: Awesome, I've added it as an answer too:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simply achieved by using the column as the JSON key when getting the appropriate rate:

```
(rates_values->currency)::float
```

(currency is the column from the second table in the question).

Answer (score 1):

You may first normalize (or flatten) the exchange rates table like this (`exchange_rates` CTE is a mimic of the real table):

```sql
with exchange_rates(id, rates_values, rate_date) as
(
 values
 (1, '{"AED":2.835349,"AFN":67.743417,"BGN":1.95582}', '2022-01-01'::date),
 (2, '{"AED":2.485349,"AFN":66.843814,"BGN":1.95582}', '2022-02-02')
)
select xr.id, l.currency, l.rate::numeric, xr.rate_date 
from exchange_rates xr
cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(xr.rates_values::jsonb) as l(currency, rate);
```

| id | currency | rate | rate_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AED | 2.835349 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | AFN | 67.743417 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | BGN | 1.95582 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | AED | 2.485349 | 2022-02-02 |
| 2 | AFN | 66.843814 | 2022-02-02 |
| 2 | BGN | 1.95582 | 2022-02-02 |

and then join with it as you need.